# Calculating internal resistance of a voltage source?

Tags: passive-networks

I am trying to do some assignment for my homework.

This is the assignment.

The voltage at voltage source is calculated with measuring device that has has 2 resistance. The voltage measured is 10V.

The resistance of voltmeter is 20K.

With adding a resistance of 5K, the voltage droped to 8V.

How big is the voltage source, internal resistance of that voltage source, and storm(I)(A I am not sure how to say it on english).

I tried to solve it in different ways, but I always end up with two unknown in one equation.

Can you tell me how to solve this. Thanks.

EDIT:
First I tried to imagine a circuit as voltage divider. That not work did work, because I got two unknowns in my equation. The real source, and the resistance.

Second attempt, was to compare two circuits. Both have the same voltage source, so I tried from there. I also didnt work.

Comment: Please show us your attempted solutions. If you have a misunderstanding we can help you to see it.

Comment: Are you trying to say "short-circuit current"?

Comment: @JoeHass I will try. I am not sure how to place picture here. When I figure it out, I will write what have I done.

Comment: @Andyaka No I am not

Comment: I don't think you need to post any pictures, and please don't take a photo of your handwritten work. Just add your equations to the question.

Comment: You're right, with these data you get two equations with three unknowns (the internal impedance of the source, the voltage output of the source and the internal impedance of the measuring device).

Can you clarify the "has has 2 resistance" part and the "storm(I)" part?

Comment: @jsrmalvarez I made a simple circuit from Ri and R2. They are in serial connection. Basicly I made a voltage divider. But I still got two unknowns.

Comment: Storm -> current. I didnt remember the transtation for the word, so I wrote storm(german)

Comment: According wikipedia it's "elektrischer Strom" :D

Comment: First, all the handwaving makes it confusing what exactly your setup is.  Show a diagram or some schematics.  Second, current in German is "Strom" not "Storm".  It doesn't say much about you if you can't even get the words of your own language right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Knowing that the input impedance of the voltmenter
is 20k we have 2 situations:

1. Voltage divider with \$_{Rout}\$ (ouput impedance of the source) and \$R_{in} = 20 k\$.
2. Voltage divider with \$_{Rout}\$ (ouput impedance of the source) and \$R = 5k // 20 k = 4k\$.

Then, 2 equations with 2 unknowns \$V_{out}\$ and \$R_{out}\$:
\$
\begin{array}{rcr}
10V = V_{out}  {{20k} \over {20k + R_{out}}};\\
 8V =  V_{out} {{4k} \over {4k + R_{out}}}
\end{array}
\$

From there, the current is trivial.

Comment: I now that input resistance of resistor is 20K ohms

Comment: Then you should add it to your post.

Comment: I was sure that I added it. Sorry

Answer (score 0):

> With adding a resistance of 5K, the voltage droped to 8V.

You should always specify whether the resistor was added in *series* or in *parallel*.

In either case, two simple voltage division equations are all that is required to solve for \$R_S\$.

If you added the resistor in series then you have the following two equations by [voltage division](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voltage_divider#Resistive_divider):

$$10V = V_S \dfrac{20k\Omega}{20k\Omega + R_S} $$

$$8V = V_S \dfrac{20k\Omega}{20k\Omega + 5k\Omega + R_S} $$

Note the added series resistor in the 2nd equation.

If you added the resistor in parallel then you have the following two equations by voltage division:

$$10V = V_S \dfrac{20k\Omega}{20k\Omega + R_S} $$

$$8V = V_S \dfrac{20k\Omega || 5k\Omega }{20k\Omega || 5k\Omega + R_S} $$

Note the added parallel resistor in the 2nd equation.